# Java HttpServletResponse with blank-value headers?

Tags: java, grails, http-headers, httpserver, servlets

How can I make a java-based application server reply with an empty-valued response header, like this?

```
content-length:\r\n
```

Unfortunately when I call

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length", len)
```

where len is either an empty string or null, the response will not include the header.

I've checked the HttpServletResponse and HttpServletResponseWrapper javadocs but couldn't figure out what could be overriden to provide my custom behaviour.

#### Background

I'm building a testing application that is supposed to emulate badly-behaved HTTP server scenarios. The application is supposed to reply to requests with preset pages and HTTP headers, including malformed ones like the above case. 
The application is written in grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm building a testing application that is supposed to emulate badly-behaved HTTP server scenarios.

In such a case, attempting to get a well-behaving server to mimic such behavior is a bad idea. If you need to mimic a bad server, or a particular set of scenarios you wish to test, then you may do one of the following:

- write a custom application that listens on a particular port (using the ServerSocket class) that will respond with malformed HTTP headers. Using HTTP libraries may not help, for libraries may have code to detect erroneous conditions and correct them automatically.
- use a HTTP proxy that is capable of intercepting responses and allows for modifications of these responses. You will find several if you Google for "http debugging proxy", but if you haven't heard of any, I would suggest looking at [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [WebScarab](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_WebScarab_Project) or [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html).

Comment: I think I will write a custom server, using netty or a raw socket implementation. Trying to hack together a solution that would work with any servlet container's implementation of HTTP proved pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a tool like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/adding-headers-and-attachments.html) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) with it's Firefox extension. I havent tried setting a malformed header with them but I wouldn't be suprised if you could.

Comment: I'd checked already SoapUI and checked Fiddler now, and while they look like very interesting tools, they don't fit the use case I'm trying to cover :P

Comment: Ah, then perhaps you should elaborate your use case. Does the 'bad behaviour emulation' have to be built into your app? If so then you can override the HttpServletResponse object to remove its  RFC 2047 validation. You will need to implement a custom filter as well in order to process incoming servlet requests, if you decide to go that route.

Comment: The idea is that the application provides an interface to create, read, update and delete from a database, and a service that responds with whatever content+headers the users put in, RFC compliant or not. So far every attempt to override HttpServletResponse's behaviour has been fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

Something not clear for me: your application is written in Grails, but you are discussing of javadocs... Well, I suppose you try to create a bad server in JAVA...

As you said, answering with "Content-Length:\r\n" is not legal for HTTP. You must put an integer value or discard the header. I think setHeader() helps you to avoid to produce an illegal HTTP message.

You can workaround this way creating manually the headers (you can write directly to the socket without using the setHeader blocks).

Other solution is to create a filter (in addition of your servlet) with your own implementation of HttpServletResponse. You will pass this implementation to the servlet.

Comment: I'm trying to go the filter route

Comment: I'm trying to go the filter route, where I inject my custom HttpServletResponseWrapper subclass into the flow. My implementation keeps the http headers (valid or not) in a separate field from the superclass'. I have overriden addHeader and setHeader to add into this field. However, I can't figure out which method(s) to override for the servlet container to extract my custom headers from this object. HttpServletResponse only seems to provide setters for the headers, but no getters...